# return a delayed nested promise in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout, q

I am using Google geocoding in my code. I have to geocode about 50 places,
but Google doesn't allow to geocode so many places at the same time, generating a 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' error.
So I want do delay the geocoding for few seconds when I exceed the quota.
I have a function `geocode()` that returns a `promise`. When I exceed quota, I want to recursively call itself.

This is my not-working code:

```
function geocodeAll(addresses)
 {
   for (addr in addresses)
     {
      geocode(addresses[addr])
        .then(
              function(coord)
               {/* I don't always get here */}
             )
     }
 }


function geocode(address)
{
 var deferred = Q.defer();
 geocoder.geocode(address, function ( err, geoData ) 
        {
         if (err)
            { deferred.reject(err);}
         else
            {
             if (geoData.status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" )
                 { // doh! quota exceeded, delay the promise
                  setTimeout(function()
                     {geocode(address)
                      .then(
                            function(coord)
                             {deferred.resolve(coord);}
                           );
                      }, 1000);
                    }
                else
                    { // everything ok
                     var coord = {'lat':geoData.lat, 'lng':geoData.lng};              
                     deferred.resolve(coord);
                    }
               }
      });

  return deferred.promise; 
}
```

UPDATE [solved]

actually the code is right. I had an uncaughtException not related to the delay. Using `Q.all([..]).then().catch()` I found it

Comment: Is your promise just never resolving, or are you getting an error?

Comment: I always get the result geocoded, but it is not returned back to the main function the  called geocode() for the first time.

Comment: You're not handling errors anywhere. How do you know you don't get one of them?

Comment: How do you know that you always get the result when it's not returned back?

Comment: Try to avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and rather promisify `geocode` and `setTimeout` on their own. If you don't want to do that, at least use `setTimeout(function() { deferred.resolve(geocode(address)); }, 1000)` to do it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine.  The only issue i see with your code is that you are using `lat` and `lng` out of scope.  But you may have written that correctly and you're just not including the code.  I suspect though that you may have been using the two in error.  Should those have been `geoData.lat` and `geoData.lng`?

`var coord = { 'lat': geoData.lat, 'lng': geoData.lng };`

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KfuBVMOoqMh8SyG7vP9L?p=preview)

**EDIT**

I think your problem might have to do with your `geocodeAll` function implementation.

```
function geocodeAll(addresses)
 {
   for (addr in addresses)
     {
      geocode(addresses[addr]) /* This seems error prone to me!  Try keeping track of all your promises.*/
        .then(
              function(coord)
               {/*You only get here if there was no error returned from the geo request to the api. */}
             )
     }
 }
```

Keep track using `Q.all`,

```
function geocodeAll(addresses) {
  var promises = addresses.map(geocode); 
  for (addr in addresses) {
    promises.push(
      geocode(addresses[addr])
         .catch(console.log.bind(console)) /* handle your error however you see fit*/
      ); 
  }
  return Q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
     var firstCord = results[0];
     var secondCord = results[1];
     //etc...
  });
 }
```

Or you can additionally handle the success/fail using `Q.allSettled`

```
function geocodeAll(addresses) {
      var promises = addresses.map(geocode);
      return Q.allSettled(promises).then(function (results) {
        var success = [], fail = [];
        results.forEach(function (result) {
          if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
             success.push(result.value);
          } else {
            fail.push(result.reason);
          }
        });
        return { coords: success, errors: fail };
      });
     }

   });
```

Comment: yes, just a typo here. It's correct in my real code. thank you, I fix the question

Comment: thank you, your code is much more clean!  now it works, it was an uncaughtException

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good. Perhaps `geocoder.geocode` or something else is erring. Try setting:

```
window.onerror = (err) => console.error(err)
```

Or:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => console.error(err))
```

Comment: You're actually looking for `process.on("unhandledRejection", console.error)`